# Django all auth: How to override the confirmation email url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, single-page-application, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

What I want to do is to override confirmation email url in `templates/account/email/email_confirmation_message.txt`.

I want to change this part

```
To confirm this is correct, go to {{ activate_url }}
```

to something like

```
http://localhost:8080/confirm_email/{{ key }}
```

However, I couldn't figure out where `{{ activate_url }}` comes from.
I want to send the `key` to the endpoint made by `rest-auth`.

How can I rewrite the url link on email? Or if it's too complitcated, what is the easy way to verify the email on frontend?

Comment: What do you mean "verify the email on frontend"? The `activate_url` is the url containing the confirmation token that allows allauth to verify this is associated with the correct email. What's `key`?

Comment: @dirkgroten Sorry I misunderstand something. `key` is what is needed to verify email. Please see the source code. I'm using `Django` as rest API. So I don't wanna use  the default `url`. The part of `{{ activate_url }}` is `key`

Comment: `key` is also a context variable passed to the template. Just write your own template.

Comment: @dirkgroten `email_confirmation_message.txt` doesn't refer to the `key`. The part of `{{ activate_url }}` is `key`

Comment: Well it is in the context, so you can use it. Look at `send_confirmation_mail()` method in allauth/account/adapter.py. This allows you to add in your template something like "if the above link doesn't work, go to `mysite.com/confirm-email` and insert this key there", presenting an extra form where they can paste the key.

Comment: @dirkgroten Sorry I didn't notice that.. I checked `views.py`.. Honestly I still don't get how  this `adapter` is used.. Thanks I think I can solve the problem now.

Comment: @dirkgroten Can I ask you one more question? In `adapter.py` the template is referred as  `email_template = 'account/email/email_confirmation'` but there is not this template. Where `email_confirmation_message.txt` is used?

Comment: The adapter uses a clever scheme that automatically checks for multiple templates. So when you see `email_confirmation`, it uses `email_confirmation_message.txt` and `email_confirmation_message.html` for the body and `email_confirmation_subject.txt` for the subject. It automatically sends a multipart message if the `.html` template is present, otherwise it only sends the text message. This is done in the `render_mail` method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The template is rendered with a context containing `user`, `current_site`, `activate_url` and `key` (see the `send_confirmation_mail()` method in *allauth/account/adapter.py*).

So you can just override the template and use `key` (and probably also `current_site` to make an absolute URI) to create your URL in the template.

Comment: how to convert http to https?

Comment: @HemanthSP depends what you're doing. The `activate_url` uses the same scheme as the `request` that is currently processed (e.g. user registering), so it should automatically be https (if you use that for user registration). If you build the url yourself in the template, just hard-code `https` or `http` depending on whether `debug` is true for example.

Comment: @giveJob this you can use using allauth setting ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = 'https'

Answer (score 4):

To fix this problem u may just need to override send_email function.

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from django.conf import settings

class CustomAllauthAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def send_mail(self, template_prefix, email, context):
    account_confirm_email = '/api/v1/auth/register/account-confirm-email/'
    context['activate_url'] = (
        settings.BASE_URL + account_confirm_email + context['key']
    )
    msg = self.render_mail(template_prefix, email, context)
    msg.send()
```

Comment: Where do I place this within a file, and where on the filesystem?

Comment: in the settings.py file, u can use this as a default email backend adapter.